# pandas `read_json` behavior with `bytes` object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, compatibility

I have multiple projects(with different `pandas` versions) which make use `pandas.read_json` for converting JSON into dataframe object. Here is the behavior with version `1.1.4` which is working as expected.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.1.4'
>>>
>>> df = pd.read_json(b'{"col": [1, 2, 3]}')
>>> df
   col
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

But testing the same code in the latest version(`1.4.0`) resulting `TypeError`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.4.0'
>>>
>>> df = pd.read_json(b'{"col": [1, 2, 3]}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
..... # Skipped traceback for brevity
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

I know this can be easily fixed by using in memory bytes stream (`BytesIO`)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> pd.__version__
'1.4.0'
>>>
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> df = pd.read_json(BytesIO(b'{"col": [1, 2, 3]}'))
>>> df
   col
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

But I am curios to understand why the latest version of `read_json` does not work with `bytes` type.

Any insights, links to Github issue/discussion will be really useful for the future readers.

Comment: FYI, a `str` object as opposed to `bytes`  works and the 1.4.0 docs say the first parameter can be a "a valid JSON str, path object or file-like object".  It doesn't mention supporting `bytes` objects, even in 1.1.  Are you using the same Python version in both projects?

Comment: I think the previous versions were buggy and it got fixed in `1.4.0`. The exact part which raises error was made via [this commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/5f36af325c276454201495eaf66be55bd17964a5)

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, Python 3.9 in both cases.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks!. Interesting to [see that](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/5f36af325c276454201495eaf66be55bd17964a5#diff-63200ddb7f5656b8ee868a28d9cb7720ffe50689b0e3fb0b4e15cc5c0ae80dd7R411) how it handle the same case with excel(but not with JSON)